# Multiselect binding in knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have html multiselect implementation, how implement knockout data-bind in javascript?

```
<select class='multiselect' data-bind="
                                        options: vm.types,
                                        value: vm.selectedTypeId, 
                                        optionsText:'type', 
                                optionsValue: 'typeId'">
                                </select>"
```

Comment: You want to use data bind in javascript? If thats what you are intersted in I guess you can do so using attr() functions

Comment: @G_S ,Yes, I want use data bind in javascript, but I think use Computed Observables

Comment: Do you mean this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

Comment: @Wayne Ellery, No, I want create datatable as http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html, but I use viewmodel and mRender

Comment: Do you want to use knockout as in the answer that I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this.
This might not be exactly what you want or a working code. But a just sample.
Try writing this in your document.ready function.
The one that I wrote is assuming that there is a tag span. I am adding data-bind to that span

```
var span=document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
var att=document.createAttribute("data-bind");
att.value="text: yourknockoutOBservable";
span.setAttributeNode(att);
```